# Zip and Unzip File in Powershell 4

Tags: powershell, zip, unzip, powershell-4.0

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 bit). I have powershell version 4 available in it. I am trying to zip and unzip files. When I try Write-Zip command, it throws me following error:

Write-Zip : The term 'Write-Zip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

What should I do to fix it? Do I need to install zip/winrar in the server? Or is there any other command do zip/unzip files?

Comment: I need to zip a folder. This folder has lot of subfolders and files. Can someone tell me how can I zip it in powershell as well as in windows command line (cmd)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`Write-Zip` seems to be part of http://pscx.codeplex.com/ that require a separate installation before you can use it.

However, if you just want to create a Zip archive from a folder, you could just run

```
$source = "c:\temp\source"
$archive = "c:\temp\archive.zip"

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $archive)
```

This utilizes the `CreateFromDirectory` method from the .NET Framework class `ZipFile`. It creates a zip archive from the files located inside the `$source` folder and creates an archive as defined in the `$archive` variable. Note, [ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class was introduced in .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: This answers the question exactly and works well without needing to upgrade or install any additional software. Great answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can use custom powershell object `New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application` and copy the file with flags to unzip.

```
$filePath = "foo.zip"
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$zipFile = $shell.NameSpace($filePath)
$destinationFolder = $shell.NameSpace("C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules")

$copyFlags = 0x00
$copyFlags += 0x04 # Hide progress dialogs
$copyFlags += 0x10 # Overwrite existing files

$destinationFolder.CopyHere($zipFile.Items(), $copyFlags)
```

Credit source https://github.com/hashicorp/best-practices/blob/master/packer/scripts/windows/install_windows_updates.ps1#L12-L22

This does not work with windows 'core' edition. If possible, upgrade to powershell 5 and use `Expand Archive` since it is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to PowerShell V5 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395), it has them natively. https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/powershell-5-zip-and-unzip/

For PowerShell version 4, you may be able to use this search http://www.powershellgallery.com/items?q=zip&x=0&y=0. This also looks to do what you are looking for: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/1.0.1.0

To install the modules, you need to type:

```
install-module -name <module name>
```

- powershellgallery.com is a free to upload site. Please check and understand module before running it.

Hope this helps.
Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks a lot for the response. But when I execute "Install-Module" command, it throws the same error as "Write-Zip" command that this cmd is not recognized.

Comment: Hi Raji, sorry. Just checked, you need PowerShell V5 to install from poweshellgallery.com. Or, use the MSI installer listed in this URL. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/readme?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Should work under PS4. See`Add-Zip` and `New-Zip`functions

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
 [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ })]
 [string]$sourceDirectory,

 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
 [ValidateScript({-not(Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf)})]
 [string]$destinationFile,

 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
 [int]$noOlderThanHours
 ) 

 function New-Zip
 { 
     param([string]$zipfilename)
     set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
     (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false
 }

 function Add-Zip
 {
    param([string]$zipfilename) 

    if(-not (test-path($zipfilename)))
    {
      set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
      (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false    

    }

    $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)


      foreach($file in $input) 
      { 
          $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
          Start-sleep -milliseconds 500
      }
 }

$oldest = (Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Hours $noOlderThanHours)

$filesToZip = dir $sourceDirectory -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt $oldest}

 Write-Host Going to zip following files 

 $filesToZip | foreach {Write-Host $_.FullName}



$filesToZip| Add-Zip $destinationFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Write-Zip installation could have been performed incorrectly. An incorrect manual edit of the environment parameter PSModulePath may cause it:

Bad (original) value:

```
PSModulePath = %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\;C:\Program Files\Intel\
```

Good value (which fixed the problem):

```
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\;%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files\Intel\
```