# Download and unzip from a batch file on Windows XP, 7 and 10?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have to download and unzip a file from a batch file on Windows 10, 7 and XP.

I am getting error from machines other than Windows 10:

> Expand-Archive : The term 'Expand-Archive' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, Script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Are there any options/common commands that will download a zip file and unzip it    for all the OS's?

Below is the code already written and working in windows 10:

```
 powershell -command "Start-BitsTransfer -Source https://prod-corp.net/public/Folder.zip -Destination C:\temp"
 powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Path C:\temp\Folder.zip -DestinationPath C:\temp -Force"
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343740/10765946 to unzip.

Comment: The error you are getting is because I am unsure that you have the BITS module installed or not. `Import-Module BitsTransfer` and see `get-help Expand-Archive` to see if it is already present. Further, I have posted an alternate solution for your qustion without any module. That should get your work done.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use `System.net.WebClient` to download any file provided you have enough permissions.

```
$WebClient_Obj = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$source = "http://url/yourFile.zip"
$destination = "C:\MyCustomFolder\YourFile.zip"
$WebClient_Obj.DownloadFile($url,$file)
```

then you can use the COM object `shell.application` to unzip it in powershell directly:

```
$shell_ComObject = New-Object -ComObject shell.application 
$zip_file = $shell_ComObject.namespace($yourfile) #in your case, it is $destination 
$folder = $shell_ComObject.namespace("C:\MyCustomFolder") 
$folder.Copyhere($zip_file.items())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is not working as it is showing below error
'$WebClient_Obj' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'$source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Antony Looks like you ran the code as a batch file instead of a PowerShell script with a `.ps1` extension or in PowerShell directly.

Comment: I have to do this in a batch file. Is there any options for that?

Comment: @Antony: Create a powershell script with .ps1 and trigger it in batch(.bat) like this `Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  C:\Users\username\Desktop\yourscript.ps1.ps1`